# php artisan ui vue get ErrorException failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm

I'm installing vuejs for my Laravel project, but when I use command with `php artisan ui vue` I got an error like this:

Please tell me how can I fix this error, thanks very much.

```
ErrorException
>
  copy(D:\Code\Hung's Friend\management\resources\sass/_variables.scss): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
>
  at D:\Code\Hung's Friend\management\vendor\laravel\ui\src\Presets\Bootstrap.php:42
    38|      * @return void
    39|      */
    40|     protected static function updateSass()
    41|     {
  > 42|         copy(__DIR__.'/bootstrap-stubs/_variables.scss', resource_path('sass/_variables.scss'));
    43|         copy(__DIR__.'/bootstrap-stubs/app.scss', resource_path('sass/app.scss'));
    44|     }
    45|
    46|     /**
>
  1   D:\Code\Hung's Friend\management\vendor\laravel\ui\src\Presets\Bootstrap.php:42
      copy("D:\Code\Hung's Friend\management\vendor\laravel\ui\src\Presets/bootstrap-stubs/_variables.scss", "D:\Code\Hung's Friend\management\resources\sass/_variables.scss")
>
  2   D:\Code\Hung's Friend\management\vendor\laravel\ui\src\Presets\Bootstrap.php:15
      Laravel\Ui\Presets\Bootstrap::updateSass()
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

You need to put two files in your resources folder

```
resources/sass/_variables.scss
resources/js/bootstrap.js
```

after you put those files run

> php artisan ui vue

Comment: Thank you Oguzhan, this work on my end on installing ui react

Comment: After receiving '‘ErrorException copy(<path_to_install>/resources/css/app.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory' - I had to create this missing css directory and blank app.css file, in order to run `php artisan breeze:install react` again without errors.

Comment: This helped me solve the same issue with `php artisan ui bootstrap` thank you.
Who would have thought the file had to be created manually?

Comment: glad it did mate :)

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir resources/js
```

should solve it then run

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
```

after

```
php artisan ui vue
```

or

```
php artisan ui react
```